# make horizontal graph with percentage :react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, charts

I trying to make a horizontal chart with  react-chartjs i want each data to show the percentage

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

import { HorizontalBar } from "react-chartjs-2";
export default class Button extends Component {
  render() {
    const dataHorBar = {
      labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
      datasets: [
        {
          label: "My First dataset",
          backgroundColor: "#EC932F",
          borderColor: "rgba(255,99,132,1)",
          borderWidth: 1,
          hoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(255,99,132,0.4)",
          hoverBorderColor: "rgba(255,99,132,1)",
          data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40]
        }
      ]
    };
    return (
      <div>
        <HorizontalBar data={dataHorBar} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Here is the code of what I have tried

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-chartjs-bar-horizontal-bar-forked-be9wil

I also want to remove the background lines and make the graph more rounded edge

Comment: What is your issue here ?

Comment: @TheTisiboth i want the data to show the persontage

Comment: as in the first picture

Comment: each bar must show its value as persontage at the end

Comment: if i knew that i wont be asking this question its oke if u dont know how to help me u can simply skip this question dont put negative on this question so some others can help me

Comment: I just try to understand how can I help you actually! So you could maybe rewrite a bit the question, so it is easyer to understand what is your issue, so it is easyer to help you with your problem.

Comment: can u make a working sandboxexample  @TheTisiboth

Comment: Could you rather explain what you tried, and what is not working, in order to see how I could help? Thank you :)

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-chartjs-bar-horizontal-bar-forked-be9wil

Comment: pls have a look at my codesandbox  i want to show at the end of each bar %  as in image

Comment: Yes, but as I told you, you can use the datalabels plugin. What is not working in your case ?

Comment: I updated my answer to show to you a be more clearly how it is working. Does that helps ?

Comment: can u pls help me with a working codesandbox i am not sure where to place the code u provided

Comment: feel free to edit my codesandbox @TheTisiboth

Comment: look at my updated answer

Comment: @TheTisiboth hello thanku for the ansswer but i have created my etire project without using typescript i use .js format so ue code is giving erroe when i save it in .js fromat can u help me with that

Comment: @TheTisiboth i am also getiing the folowwing error `Module not found: Can't resolve 'chart.js/auto' in 'C:\Users\vivek\newcode\react-shebirth\src\doctor\analatics\analatics_graph'`

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue, it is working well here : https://codesandbox.io/s/goofy-butterfly-qcsv1v?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0):

In order to use the feature for having rounded rectangles, you need to update to the v3 of `chartjs`, therefore, the following code will be working only on this version. But you can adapt it to a previous version, you will just not be able to change the border radius of the rectangle.

You can use the [datalabels](https://chartjs-plugin-datalabels.netlify.app/) plugin, in order to display custom text in your chart, and format the label like this:

```
options: {
    plugins: {
      datalabels: {
        formatter: value => value + " %", // Add the percentage after the value
        align: "end",
        anchor: "end",
        clip: true,
      }
    }
  }
```

For the shapes, you can use the option `borderRadius`, to have rounded edges. You can find more information [here](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/3.5.0/samples/bar/border-radius.html), but in the end, you just have to specify a value for the `borderRadius`, in each `dataset`:

```
datasets: [
        {
          label: "My First dataset",
          backgroundColor: "#EC932F",
          borderColor: "rgba(255,99,132,1)",
          borderWidth: 1,
          hoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(255,99,132,0.4)",
          hoverBorderColor: "rgba(255,99,132,1)",
          data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40],
          borderRadius: 50, // Give a number
        }
      ]
```

Finally, for removing the grid lines, you can use this snippet, and pass those options to your chart

```
options: {
    scales: {
      x: {
        grid: {
          display: false // Hide x grid
        }
      },
      y: {
        grid: {
          display: false // Hide y grid
        }
      }
    }
  };
```

That's it for the ground principle. Here is a [live working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/stacked100-cmwjlr?file=/src/App.tsx:1270-1500), if you really wants to see how to implement it.